# DISPLAY environment location in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, environment-variables

In Ubuntu, when the user logs in, then the Xserver starts and it sets the value for the DISPLAY environment variable. I wanted to know the location, like the file from which I can access this DISPLAY environment variable.

Comment: Non-persistent environment variables are not stored in a file. They are stored in the user's environment until logout. You access them by querying the environment (`echo $DISPLAY`). Of course, anything the user is running *already* knows the DISPLAY, so why do you need to "access" it?

Comment: @user535733 here is the complete context for this question : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1475232/accessing-display-environment-variable-in-systemd-service-file

Comment: Please do not repeatedly ask the same question. The etiquette here is to edit and improve your question. Since you have superseded this question with another, please be a thoughtful community member and close this one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing DISPLAY environment variable in systemd service file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1475232/accessing-display-environment-variable-in-systemd-service-file)