# Accessing DISPLAY environment variable in systemd service file

Tags: bash, services, environment-variables

I have a systemd service in user session. When the user logs in, this DISPLAY is set (by the Xserver) and I want to access the DISPLAY environment in the service file.

This is my service unit.

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/home/vipul.gupta/MyWorkspace/GTKdir/GTKTest
Environment=?
Type=simple
```

I want to provide this Environment value. I know that I can hardcode this value as
`Environment=Display=:10.0`

,but I want the service unit to access the DISPLAY variable set for that user session.

Note: DISPLAY is not accessible by the systemd as it is not available in the output of the command : `systemctl --user show-environment`. Hence the question.

Comment: This looks like a design problem. There are several approaches. The simplest is to use Startup Applications instead of a user service. Another approach is to use two applications in a client-server relationship communicating via Dbus.

Comment: Is there a reason why systemd is not accessing the DISPLAY. Is it something that I might have missed that is causing the systemd to not access the DISPLAY?

Comment: Unable to reproduce the issue: On my Ubuntu Desktop 23.04 test system (stock install), systemd **does** see the DISPLAY environment variable, and happily outputs it using `systemctl --user show-environment | grep DISPLAY`